# XAML, binding Width and Height properties to the same properties of other control

Tags: xaml, binding, user-controls, height, width

I'm trying to create a reflection effect and it's working great except that I have to hard-code some values. This is my XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <UserControl x:Name="CurrentPresenter" />
        <Border Width="500" Height="200" >
            <Border.Background>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter}" >
                    <VisualBrush.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" CenterX="500" CenterY="99" />
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </VisualBrush.Transform>
                </VisualBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.OpacityMask>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,0.6">
                        <GradientStop Offset="-0.6" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.6" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.OpacityMask>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I've tried to replace Border's `Width="500"` and `Height="200"` by `Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=Width}"` and `Height="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=Height}"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Wha's wrong with this code?

UPDATE: If I set Width and Height here:

```
<UserControl x:Name="CurrentPresenter" Height="200" Width="500" />
```

It works as expected. However it doesn't work if I set those values in the UserControl XAML. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what kind of behaviour are you actually seeing? Does the Border appear too small, or does it just keep stretching infinitely (I've seen both).

Comment: It stretches to fill the conatiner.

Comment: If you set the height and width in the UserControl XAML, does the UserControl appear to be the right size and it's just the Border that's stretching, or are both controls the wrong size?

Comment: If I set the height and width in the UserControl XAML, the UserControl is displayed with the correct size, however the border stretches to fill the container. It seems that if I don't set explicitly the width and height values the binding doesn't work. I'm going to workaround this by creating the "reflection effect" inside the usercontrol, but I'm just curious about why this doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 22):

Rather than bind to the Height and Width properties of the UserControl, have you tried binding the `Height` and `Width` properties of the `Border` to the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` properties of the UserControl?

```
<Border 
 Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualWidth}"
 Height="{Binding ElementName=CurrentPresenter, Path=ActualHeight}" >
```

Comment: This fix saved a few gray hairs. Thanks Tabby.

Answer (score 0):

change path to ViewportWidth! its work for me